# hide bullets in the resulting list of titles

Tags: javascript, hide

how do I hide bullets in the resulting list of titles pls?

this code displays a lists of blogspot.com post titles with bullets. I do not know how to change it to remove or hide the bullets

```
<div id="all_post_root">Loading ...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Sort the items with respect to their title
var entriesComparator = function(a, b) {
return a.link[2].title > b.link[2].title;
}

var displayFeed = function(response) {
var entries = response.feed.entry;
entries.sort(entriesComparator);

var listUl = document.createElement("ul");
for (var i in entries) {
var elt = entries[i].link[2];

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = elt.href;
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elt.title));

var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(a);

listUl.appendChild(li);
}

var allPostRoot = document.getElementById('all_post_root');
allPostRoot.innerHTML = "";
allPostRoot.appendChild(listUl);
};
</script>

<script src="/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&callback=displayFeed">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write CSS class just like Micke W showed, do add

```
    var listUl = document.createElement("ul");
    listUl.style.listStyleType = 'none';
```

This will set the `list-style-type`  to `none` inline with the `ul` element.

Answer (score 2):

Set `list-style-type:none` in the CSS that refers to the `<li>` elements where you want to hide the bullets.

Add a class to the `<ul>` element:

```
var listUl = document.createElement("ul class='nobullets'");
```

And add an entry to your style sheet:

```
.nobullets li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```